# Inno Setup - delete a temp folder

Tags: windows, inno-setup, uninstallation, temp

When I want to delete my application (that was installed through an installer with Inno Setup), anything related to it should be removed from my drive.

So my goal is to also delete a temp folder that was created at runtime by my application.

Unfortunately, this line of code was not able to solve my problem

```
[UninstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{tmp}\MyTempFolder"
```

I get this error message in the Debug Output:

`Failed to delete directory (145). Will retry later.`

Comment: 145 means the directory is not empty. What has remained in it? Did you check the uninstaller log file if it has more information?

Comment: I cannot find the uninstaller log file, but I just changed my code to:

Type: files; Name: "{tmp}\MyTempFolder\TmpUserSettings.json"

Now I am getting this error: Failed to delete the file; it may be in use (32).

Comment: And is it in use? What process is using it?

Comment: No it is not! I closed all applications

Comment: How exactly did do you check that?

Comment: Get Process Explorer, it can tell you exactly what program / process has a file open.